# Golang "plugin was built with a different version of package" when testing

Tags: go, plugins

I am developing a project where plugins are built on startup:

```golang
func BuildPlugin(path *string) error {
    buildGo := "go"
    buildArgs := []string{
        "build",
        "-buildmode=plugin",
        "-o",
        filepath.Join(*path, "ext/ext.so"),
        filepath.Join(*path, "ext/ext.go"),
    }

    cmd := exec.Command(buildGo, buildArgs...)
    _, err := cmd.Output()

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

When I run the program, the plugins load successfully, however when I run the tests, I get the following error:

`fsm_test.go:34: plugin.Open("../examples/00_test/ext/ext"): plugin was built with a different version of package github.com/jaimeteb/chatto/fsm`

I have read some solutions for similar problems but none have worked yet.

This is the project in question: [github.com/jaimeteb/chatto](https://github.com/jaimeteb/chatto/tree/dev)

Answer (score 4):

Go plugins are really nifty, but their biggest drawback is that the versions of Go that both the plugin and consumer binaries are built with have to match *exactly*. This is really the biggest thing that's kept me from using them more often, opting instead for RPC-based plugin libraries like `hashicorp/go-plugin`.

If you opt to keep going with Go plugins, you'll need to rebuild the project's plugins whenever you change Go's versions, or maybe even whenever you build your consuming project.